# ASP.NET Core API static files authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-client-side

I am not sure if this has been asked again, but in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization) I saw how to enable static file authorization for MVC projects.

I am building a Blazor WASM AspNet hosted site which will act as an image gallery website where people will be able to upload images.

The requirement is to add authorization so that a user should be able to see only images he owns. 
This is already implemented but the issue is that the images uploaded are saved as static files on the back-end server, under `wwwroot`, and are by default public available.

I tried to use another approach to upload the images as `byte[]` directly in `MSSQL` but I don't think it is a good idea to store images in db.

I also tried to read the bytes from the static files on the API and return them as `base64` encoded strings to the client, but this is also not a good approach for large images.

The only approach I see fit is to save images as static files on the back-end, save the links to them in database and expose the files for authorized users somehow?

Is this possible?

Comment: What prevents you from storing the files in a different directory on the web server? Something other than wwwroot?
And yeah if the files are small, you could store them in a DB, or you use a different file storage service like blob storage and have a container per user for example.

Comment: @MichaC How can I serve them as a static file if it is not public available? For example to be able to access the image it should be saved in a public available URL `http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg`. If `images/image1.jpg` it is not public the image will not be displayed. Or I am missing something?

Comment: The example is in the docs document you linked. You point to the file location and return a File IActionResult from the controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to serve the files from a controller action instead of static files, then you can use the `[Authorize]` attribute like you ussually do. Don't save your images in the wwwroot folder.

```
public IActionResult DisplayImage() => new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(pathToImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "image/png");
```